# Limit of sequence of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{x_n\}$ be sequence of real numbers such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=p$.

Also if $m\to \infty$ then $n\to \infty$ and converse.

How to prove strictly $\lim_{m\to\infty} x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty} x_m=p$?

I met this feint in many books and also in my last problem that I solved but I can't understand this.

Comment: What do you mean by $\lim_{m\to\infty} x_n$ ? Do you actually want to prove, that every subsequence of converging sequence is also converging to the same limit?

Comment: I agree with the comment above. The expression $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_m$ can make sense if $m$ is a function of $n$, but the expression $\lim_{m\to\infty}x_n$ makes no sense without some further explanation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $m(n)$ be a monotone function $\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$, then $(x_m):=(x_{m(n)})$ is a subsequence of $(x_n)$. Because each subsequence of a convergent sequence converges to the same limit as the original sequence, you have $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_{m(n)} = p$.

Comment: monotone is not needed, $m(n)\to\infty$ should be enough (and would possibly match the OP's notion "$m\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$")

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen,  why for $m(n)$ monotone is not needed? Can you give example?

Answer (score 1):

Well let's go back to the definition of limits as other answers seems to call the result which you willing to demonstrate :

Def of $(x_{n})$ converges to $p$ L : $\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb N, \forall n>N,  x_{n}\in B(p,\varepsilon) $

For $\varepsilon > 0$, as $(x_{n})$ converges to $p$ let N be such an integer, as $m(n) \rightarrow \infty $ , let $M$ be an integer such that $  \forall n>M, m(n)>N $, and we have $\forall n>M,  x_{m(n)}\in B(p,\varepsilon) $

Comment: you probably mean $B(p,\varepsilon)$?

Comment: yeah thx. Need a good WE haha

Comment: sure thing, and welcome to the math.SE community!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** Let $m\colon\mathbf N\to\mathbf N$ be a function of $n$, i.e., $m(n)$. With $m\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$, we are stating $\lim_{n\to\infty}m_n=\infty$, i.e., for any $M>0$, there exists a $N\ge0$ such that $m_n>M$ for every $n\ge N$.

By defnition of convergence of $(x_n)^\infty_{n=0}$: for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $N\ge0$ such that $|x_j-p|<\epsilon$ for every $j\ge N$.

With these facts: ¿we can pick a integer $N':=m(j)$ for some $j\in\mathbf N$ such that $N'\ge N$, and this $N'$ satisfies the definition of convergence?

---

To see the relation, you can prove

Let $(a_n)^\infty_{n=m}$ be a sequence of real numbers, and let $L\in\mathbf R$. Then the following two statementes are logically equivalent:

1. The sequence $(a_n)^\infty_{n=m}$ converges to $L$.
2. Every subsequence of  $(a_n)^\infty_{n=m}$ converge to $L$.

Comment: why $f$ is increasing?

Comment: I modified the answer without using $f$. I meant to sat that there is a subsequence of $m(n)$.